# .htaccess mod_rewrite challenge

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a series of mod_rewrite rules to make pretty urls.

I want to serve up `index.php?section=123&area=345&option=1 as /123/345/option=1`

So far so good—this works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2&$3
```

Ok here's my first problem:

1. How do I force it to work if one of the variables isn't defined, ie. if someone browses to `/section` rather than `/section/area/`. Can I make the htaccess automatically create `/area/` as default if it's been left off?
2. Similarly, how do I force the `/area/` to have a trailing slash? If it doesn't have a trailing slash at present, I get a 404 since the system is looking for but not finding the third variable.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this,

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)|(.+)/(.+)/?|(.+)/?$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2&$3
```

You ma separate those sub patters by [OR] flag.

This pattern may not out of box. You may need to revise.

Comment: Thanks this pointed me nicely in the right direction. I ended up separating out the different rules for clarity, but this is essentially an adaptation of your code:

`RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2&$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /index.php?section=$1 [L]`

This deals with the trailing slash issue, and I will use PHP to define a default area if needed.

Answer (score 0):

This could get quite ugly as you are trying to "validate" user's url input.

You might want to separate them to make it more maintainable in the long run, or in the case you want to add some more twists.

Here is an example:

```
#sunshine case
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ /index.php?section=$1&area=$2&$3

#if user enter /123/option=1, ie forgot 456 as the area
RewriteRule ^(.+)/option=(.+)$ /index.php?section=$1&area=default&$2
```

I'm not sure what's you issue with trailing slash, won't the url become `123/456option=1?`
Anyway some guide can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html).

*My opinion:
If the user want to enter url by themselves instead of relying on the links your site provides, stop rewrite the url and give them the 404, I wouldn't encourage user errors*